# about discrete and continuous variables relationships exploration

Tags: r, correlation, discrete-data, pearson-r

I have a dataset with a dependent variable that is discrete. It can take only six values. The input variables are all continuous. I am using R to do data exploration. I am using boxplot(discrete vs continuous) instead of scatter plot which looks strange. 
1. I am using corr command to get the correlation value. My primary question is with regards to the correlation coefficients I get from R. Most of the literature states the Pearson coefficient is only for continuous variables. But I don't see why I can't use to see the "relation" between discrete and continuous variables? 
Or are there other coefficients I could use? 
I am fairly new at this any literature reference would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> have a dataset with a dependent variable that is discrete. It can take only six values.

You need to specify the problem a bit further. The discrete variable is either *ordinal* (meaning that there is a meaning to the order of the discrete values) or *categorical*/*nominal* (meaning that the values are just encodings to integers, but the order between these integers has no inherent meaning).

If the discrete value is ordinal, you can use - for each independent variable and the dependent variable - Spearman's test ([R implementation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pspearman/versions/0.1-10/topics/spearman.test)) which is a non-parametric test which cares not about the distributions, and so ordinal is fine for it. As Nick Cox points out below, if the value is ordinal, it might even be *proportional*, e.g., as when it is the numerator of a fraction, in which case you can do even better than a non-parametric test.

If the discrete variable is categorical, you can use - for each independent variable and the dependent variable - [Kruskal-Wallis non-parametric one-way ANOVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Wallis_one-way_analysis_of_variance) ([R implementation](http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/non-parametric-methods/kruskal-wallis-test)). If the test shows significance, you can proceed with Dunn's test ([R implementation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dunn.test/index.html)) to see what exactly it is.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is the result of "service survey". So, it starts at 0(bad), 1(not bad), 2(ok), etc. I only have the numerical values. Yes, there is meaning to the order because the small values are indication of bad service and high value is excellent service.

Comment: @Josef So then it's ordinal, and a Spearman's will do the job.

Comment: In principle you could have counted fractions as well as ordinal or nominal variables with just 6 distinct values (or any other number). Say students take 5 exams and pass or fail each, so the possible number of passes is a a count, or equivalently a fraction, 0/5, 1/5, ..., 5/5. That measurement scale is more than ordinal as differences and ratios all make sense. (X passed one more exam than Y; U passed twice as many exams as V.) So, there are more flavours to discrete than those you mentioned. It turns out that the OP's example is not of this form, but such variables are common.

Comment: (ctd) Binomial distributions are the simplest reference distribution for such variables.

Comment: @NickCox That is an excellent point, thanks! I'll update the answer.

Comment: Your edit doesn't capture my point completely: a counted fraction is ratio scale.

Comment: @NickCox Isn't a counted fraction a special cases of a proportional ordinal? I could see why taking a logarithm of an ordinal, could change things (e.g., the Pearson correlation), but how would dividing or multiplying it by a constant?

Comment: It's ordinal, but more than ordinal.

Comment: @NickCox Sorry, but I'm probably missing your meaning. I already agreed with your insightful comment that it is more than ordinal, in the sense that not only is it monotonic, the differences are proportional to something. My comparison of ratio isn't to ordinal, but to proportional ordinal.

Comment: My point is that on the standard scale Nominal - Ordinal - Interval - Ratio (which has many limitations, but leave that aside) counted fractions qualify as ratio scale. You're still writing that discrete means nominal or ordinal, but discrete can mean interval or ratio. If you're invoking the idea that (e.g.) all ratio scale measurements also are ordinal, then naturally I agree, but I still think your answer needs rewriting to be as clear as possible to as many people as possible.

Comment: @NickCox Got it. I'll update it a bit later.